# Using Enum values as String literals

Tags: java, string, enums

What is the best way to use the values stored in an Enum as String literals?
For example:

```
public enum Modes {
    some-really-long-string,
    mode1,
    mode2,
    mode3
}
```

Then later I could use `Mode.mode1` to return its string representation as `mode1`. Without having to keep calling `Mode.mode1.toString()`.

Answer (score 795, accepted):

You can't. I think you have FOUR options here. All four offer a solution but with a slightly different approach...

**Option One:** *use the built-in `name()` on an enum. This is perfectly fine if you don't need any special naming format.*

```
    String name = Modes.mode1.name(); // Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration.
```

**Option Two:** *add overriding properties to your enums if you want more control*

```
public enum Modes {
    mode1 ("Fancy Mode 1"),
    mode2 ("Fancy Mode 2"),
    mode3 ("Fancy Mode 3");

    private final String name;       

    private Modes(String s) {
        name = s;
    }

    public boolean equalsName(String otherName) {
        // (otherName == null) check is not needed because name.equals(null) returns false 
        return name.equals(otherName);
    }

    public String toString() {
       return this.name;
    }
}
```

**Option Three:** *use static finals instead of enums:*

```
public final class Modes {

    public static final String MODE_1 = "Fancy Mode 1";
    public static final String MODE_2 = "Fancy Mode 2";
    public static final String MODE_3 = "Fancy Mode 3";

    private Modes() { }
}
```

**Option Four:** *interfaces have every field public, static and final:*

```
public interface Modes {

    String MODE_1 = "Fancy Mode 1";
    String MODE_2 = "Fancy Mode 2";
    String MODE_3 = "Fancy Mode 3";  
}
```

Comment: This answer is in fact wrong: as you can call `.name()` See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6667365/887836

Comment: @kato2 not correct. The .name() method is created automatically by the compiler

Comment: JavaDoc: 
**String java.lang.Enum.name()**

Returns the name of this enum constant, exactly as declared in its enum declaration. **Most programmers should use the toString method in preference to this one, as the toString method may return a more user-friendly name.** This method is designed primarily for use in specialized situations where correctness depends on getting the exact name, which will not vary from release to release.
Returns:the name of this enum constant

Comment: The awser of @Ryan Stewart requires less code and less code == less chance of bugs

Comment: Don't use interfaces to hold constants: *Effective Java* (3rd edition) recommends to "use interfaces only to define types" (item 22).

Comment: Option 2 is not correct. For the working implementation of Option 2, check @vamsi answer below.

Comment: @MertCelik Can you elaborate what is wrong with Option2 here?

Comment: How is using .name() any better than the .toString() that the OP was trying to avoid?

Answer (score 560):

Every enum has both a `name()` and a `valueOf(String)` method. The former returns the string name of the enum, and the latter gives the enum value whose name is the string. Is this like what you're looking for?

```
String name = Modes.mode1.name();
Modes mode = Modes.valueOf(name);
```

There's also a static `valueOf(Class, String)` on `Enum` itself, so you could also use:

```
Modes mode = Enum.valueOf(Modes.class, name);
```

Comment: THIS should be an ANSWER! Using something like A("A") can be source of errors and it is senseless extra work!

Comment: @Firzen not if the string value is allowed to contain spaces or hyphens, which is the case in `some-really-long-string`.

Comment: @ceving The question is not phrased well in respect to spaces and hyphens. The questions shows a hyphenated example, but doesn't ask how to create an Enum using hyphenated values. Instead the question asks how to get the String value without having to call toString without specifying hyphenated values are a requirement. That said, I think this could be a better answer if it were amended to mention that the Enum values must still follow Java naming rules and would need to use something mentioned in the accepted answer if such characters were required.

Comment: I wanted to add a link to [mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-convert-string-to-enum-object/) who uses the `valueOf(String)` method in combination with `toUpperCase(Locale)` to ensure String conversion.

Comment: The reason a lot of people prefer the property approach over Enum.name() is that logic based around Enum.name() is then forever at the mercy of the value names. If the code every changes in the future this could turn into a non trivial issue to get around as all the previous logic will break on changes to the Enum value set.
Overriding and using the toString() approach allows the developer to have greater control over the values in use including duplication, non valid variable name characters etc.
Just don't forget to also override valueOf().

Comment: Will the name change when using proguard? I want to use an enum name for logging, so it needs to stay the same.

Answer (score 103):

You could override the `toString()` method for each enum value.

**Example:**

```
public enum Country {

  DE {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Germany";
    }
  },
  IT {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "Italy";
    }
  },
  US {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return "United States";
    }
  }

}
```

**Usage:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(Country.DE); // Germany
  System.out.println(Country.IT); // Italy
  System.out.println(Country.US); // United States
}
```

Comment: I like this. No reason not to use an enum as a class with further functionality such as get a list of all the values, get a string of each type, etc.

Comment: Ugly and not reusable. Much better to provide a string value as constructor for Country and then override the toString() method for the enum.

Comment: @Larry should revisit this and tell if the original question required something else. Though other answers are very informative, I guess this is the only answer to the original question.

Comment: This is a good technique when you have quite a large enumeration and only want to override what things print as for one or two members.

Comment: This doesn't scale at all. Don't do this.

Comment: This works great for those smaller enums with under 5 values.

Answer (score 54):

As Benny Neugebauer mentions, you could overwrite the toString(). However instead overwriting the toString for each enum field I like more something like this:

```
public enum Country{
    SPAIN("España"),
    ITALY("Italia"),
    PORTUGAL("Portugal");


    private String value;

    Country(final String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.getValue();
    }
}
```

You could also add a static method to retrieve all the fields, to print them all, etc.
Simply call getValue to obtain the string associated to each Enum item

Answer (score 35):

`mode1.name()` or `String.valueOf(mode1)`. It doesn't get better than that, I'm afraid

Answer (score 31):

```
public enum Modes {
  MODE1("Mode1"),
  MODE2("Mode2"),
  MODE3("Mode3");

 private String value;
 public String getValue() {
    return value;
   }
 private Modes(String value) {
  this.value = value;
 } 
}
```

you can make a call like below wherever you want to get the value as a string from the enum.

```
Modes.MODE1.getvalue();
```

This will return "Mode1" as a String.

Answer (score 9):

For my enums I don't really like to think of them being allocated with 1 String each.  This is how I implement a toString() method on enums.

```
enum Animal
{
    DOG, CAT, BIRD;
    public String toString(){
        switch (this) {
            case DOG: return "Dog";
            case CAT: return "Cat";
            case BIRD: return "Bird";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Throwing a runtime exception would be better instead of returning null since it should be unreachable code?

Comment: The `return` is redundant, because switch on enums with all enums is terminating.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, the only way to get the name would be

```
Mode.mode1.name();
```

If you really need it this way, however, you could do:

```
public enum Modes {
    mode1 ("Mode1"),
    mode2 ("Mode2"),
    mode3 ("Mode3");

    private String name;       

    private Modes(String s) {
        name = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: But in this case, `Mode.mode1` is still not of type `String`.

Comment: Oh right. You'd need a getName() method, which kind of defeats the purpose, so no, you cannot do this.

Comment: "name" is bad field name, it is standart field of enum.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Mode.mode1.name()` however you often don't need to do this.

```
Mode mode =
System.out.println("The mode is "+mode);
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the + operator will call toString() on the enum, and not name(). And toString() may be overridden to return something other than the name (even if it isn't desirable)

Comment: Both `name()` and `toString()` can be overriden, but hopefully this will be clear from reading the code for the `enum` if this is happening.

Comment: No. name() is final, and always returns the name of the enum as declared in its enum declaration.

Comment: @JB Nizet, You are right. `name()` is `final`. Thank you for correcting me. :)

Answer (score 6):

my solution for your problem!

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public enum MapEnumSample {
    Mustang("One of the fastest cars in the world!"), 
    Mercedes("One of the most beautiful cars in the world!"), 
    Ferrari("Ferrari or Mercedes, which one is the best?");

    private final String description;
    private static Map<String, String> enumMap;

    private MapEnumSample(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getEnumValue() {
        return description;
    }

    public static String getEnumKey(String name) {
        if (enumMap == null) {
            initializeMap();
        }
        return enumMap.get(name);
    }

    private static Map<String, String> initializeMap() {
        enumMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for (MapEnumSample access : MapEnumSample.values()) {
            enumMap.put(access.getEnumValue(), access.toString());
        }
        return enumMap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // getting value from Description
        System.out.println(MapEnumSample.getEnumKey("One of the fastest cars in the world!"));

        // getting value from Constant
        System.out.println(MapEnumSample.Mustang.getEnumValue());

        System.out.println(MapEnumSample.getEnumKey("One of the most beautiful cars in the world!"));
        System.out.println(MapEnumSample.Mercedes.getEnumValue());

        // doesnt exist in Enum
        System.out.println("Mustang or Mercedes, which one is the best?");
        System.out.println(MapEnumSample.getEnumKey("Mustang or Mercedes, which one is the best?") == null ? "I don't know!" : "I believe that "
                + MapEnumSample.getEnumKey("Ferrari or Mustang, which one is the best?") + " is the best!.");

        // exists in Enum
        System.out.println("Ferrari or Mercedes, wich one is the best?");
        System.out.println(MapEnumSample.getEnumKey("Ferrari or Mercedes, which one is the best?") == null ? "I don't know!" : "I believe that "
                + MapEnumSample.getEnumKey("Ferrari or Mercedes, which one is the best?") + " is the best!");

    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the OP's problem was solved 4 years ago, but welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Thanks, just to help somebody like me, looking for more objective answers to old problems :)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use:

```
""+ Modes.mode1
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure on this but as far as my knowledge goes this cast isn't necessary, is it? Concatenating an empty string with another variable should automatically call for a conversion, or are there any exceptions to this rule?

Comment: You are right, the correct version should be `"" + Modes.mode1`. I fixed the answer

Comment: E B's answer also benefits by being reminiscent of the python idiom 
    `''.join()`

Answer (score 5):

```
public enum Environment
{
    PROD("https://prod.domain.com:1088/"),
    SIT("https://sit.domain.com:2019/"),
    CIT("https://cit.domain.com:8080/"),
    DEV("https://dev.domain.com:21323/");

    private String url;

    Environment(String envUrl) {
        this.url = envUrl;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
}

String prodUrl = Environment.PROD.getUrl();
```

It will print:

```
https://prod.domain.com:1088/
```

This design for [enum string constants](https://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/enum/java-enum-string-example/) works in most of the cases.

Comment: Oh. It's just like Rust and Haskell.

Comment: Why is this returning PROD to me?

Answer (score 4):

Enum is just a little bit special class. Enums can store additional fields, implement methods etc. For example

```
public enum Modes {
    mode1('a'),
    mode2('b'),
    mode3('c'),
    ;
    char c;

    private Modes(char c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    public char character() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Now you can say:

`System.out.println(Modes.mode1.character())`

and see output: 
`a`

Answer (score 3):

```
package com.common.test;

public  enum Days {


    monday(1,"Monday"),tuesday(2,"Tuesday"),wednesday(3,"Wednesday"),
    thrusday(4,"Thrusday"),friday(5,"Friday"),saturday(6,"Saturday"),sunday(7,"Sunday");

    private int id;
    private String desc;


    Days(int id,String desc){
        this.id=id;
        this.desc=desc;
    }

    public static String getDay(int id){

        for (Days day : Days.values()) {
            if (day.getId() == id) {
                return day.getDesc();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }



};
```

Comment: Can you pls explain on how it would resolve the issue ?

Comment: you can call this enum anywhere by using this line :   int id=1;  String dayName = Days.getDay(id);   , pass here id . it will return Description for that id that is "Tuesday"

Answer (score 3):

This method should work with any `enum`:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE1,
    VALUE2,
    VALUE3;

    public int getValue() {
        return this.ordinal();
    }

    public static DataType forValue(int value) {
        return values()[value];
    }

    public String toString() {
        return forValue(getValue()).name();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i found this one is more easy for preventing type error:

```
public enum Modes {
    some-really-long-string,
    mode1,
    mode2,
    mode3;

    String str;

    Modes(){
        this.str = super.name();
    }

    @Override
    @NonNull
    public String toString() {
        return str;
    }
```

however - this may work when you need to use a String on a log/println or whenever java compiles the toString() method automatically, but on a code line like this ->

```
// sample method that require (string,value)
intent.putExtra(Modes.mode1 ,shareElement.getMode()); // java error
// first argument enum does not return value
```

instead as mentioned above you will still have to extend the enum and use **`.name()`**  in those cases like this:

```
intent.putExtra(Modes.mode1.name() ,shareElement.getMode());
```

Answer (score 1):

use `mode1.name()` or `String.valueOf(Modes.mode1)`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

after many tries I have come with this solution

```
public static enum Operation {

    Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, Division,;

    public String getUserFriendlyString() {
        if (this==Addition) {
            return " + ";
        } else if (this==Subtraction) {
            return " - ";
        } else if (this==Multiplication) {
            return " * ";
        } else if (this==Division) {
            return " / ";
        }
        return "undefined";
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
public enum Modes {
    some-really-long-string,
    mode1,
    mode2,
    mode3;

    public String toString(){
        switch(this) {
            case some-really-long-string:
                return "some-really-long-string";
            case mode2:
                return "mode2";
            default: return "undefined";
        }
    }
```

}