# Why toString is not called for functions parameter?

Tags: java, tostring, charsequence

I have and Enum for my intent Extras I like to use in my android app.
The type defenition is written like this:

```
public enum Extras { TITLE, ID_USER } // ... and some more Extras
```

in my code I like to use the Enums like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(); 
i.putExtra( Extras.TITLE  , "My Title String");
i.putExtra( Extras.ID_USER, 5);
```

And

```
 String title = i.getStringExtra(Extras.TITLE);
 int userId   = i.getIntExtra(Extras.ID_USER, -1);
```

as I know enums have a toString method, my Enum `Extras.TITLE` should be automatically be casted to the String `"TITLE"`.

Its even working if I print it to screen like this

```
System.out.println("Extra="+Extras.TITLE);
```

But for the Intent Methods I get the error message:

```
The method putExtra(String, CharSequence) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (Extras, CharSequence)
```

I could avoid this error if manually convert the enum to String like this:

```
i.putExtra( Extras.TITLE.name()  , "My Title String");
i.putExtra( Extras.TITLE.toString()  , "My Title String");
```

But I like to know why to String issn`t called automatically when I pass my Enum as parameter to this method ?

Is there a way to to pass my Enums without calling toString() ?

UPDATE:
I tried to change my Enum to implement CharSequence interface.
After this modification I can pass my Enums to methods which expect `CharSequence` parameters.
But it is still incompatible with String methods.

```
public static enum Extras implements CharSequence { TITLE, ID_USER; // ... and some more Extras

    @Override  public char charAt( int index )                       { return this.toString().charAt(index);           }
    @Override  public int length()                                   { return this.toString().length();                }
    @Override  public CharSequence subSequence( int start, int end ) { return this.toString().subSequence(start, end); }
}
```

Comment: "as I know enums have a toString method, my Enum Extras.TITLE should be automatically be casted to the String "TITLE"" - how would you expect that to happen automatically? Which Java language rule would you expect to do this? There's no string concatenation here, which is all that calls `toString` automatically...

Comment: Everything but primitives has a toString() method. Note that there is no casting going on here: it's merely a method call that provides a string representation.

Comment: If you really, really hate typing the `.toString()`, use automatic conversion by prefixing `""+`

Comment: The point I don`t unterstand is, why is toString not called automatically when my Enum is passed to a function wich expects a String parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, [Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) in [`Java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) are `Integer` values. You cannot cannot get the `String` value without calling `toString()` method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667243/using-enum-values-as-string-literals) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978654/best-way-to-create-enum-of-strings) for further info.

Comment: I have already seen both of this posts, but they were not helpfull.
I yust like to know why toString is call automatically when i print it to screen, but not when I pass my Enum to a function.

Comment: @Radon8472 It's not called _automatically_. There's an `Object` version which is what responds to the `Integer`, and _in the code of that method_ they manually call `.toString`.