# Create Class from String input

Tags: java, processing

My goal is this: Be able to save an array of objects (in this case; `Animal`) to disc. Then I would like to be able to load them. I have used JSON to do this, but left it out in this snippet for clarity. I would like to be able to make many more classes of `Animal` that will have many more fields (see `Unicorn` `Class` below).

The class of the object cannot be known in advance. How can I get `addAnimal` to work using a `String` input?

```
AnimalWrangler aw;

void setup()
{
  aw = new AnimalWrangler();

  aw.addAnimal("cat");
  aw.addAnimal("horse");
  aw.addAnimal("unicorn");
  aw.addAnimal("unknown");
}

class AnimalWrangler
{

  ArrayList<Animal> animals;

  AnimalWrangler()
  {
    animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
  }

  void addAnimal(String type)
  {
    //makes an animal according to type        

    ///if type does not exist then throw

    //add to animals array 

  }
}



class Animal
{
  String type;

  Animal()
  {
  }
}

class Cat extends Animal
{
  Animal animal;
  Cat()
  {
    animal = new Animal();
    type = "cat";
  }
}

class Horse extends Animal
{
  Animal animal;
  Horse()
  {
    animal = new Animal();
    type = "horse";
  }
}

class Unicorn extends Animal
{
  Animal animal;
  float magic_level;
  /////classes can have any number of attributes

  Unicorn()
  {
    animal = new Animal();
    type = "unicorn";
  }
}
```

Comment: Your problem really looks like a NoSQL database with document approach...

Comment: Your `Animal` subclasses probably shouldn't have an `Animal animal` field...

Comment: @king_nak yes! this is just an artefact of an earlier (incorrect) approach and should be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

The typical way is to create a registry of string-to-class mappings:

```
static Map<String, Class<? extends Animal>> registry;
```

Then populate the map with the types:

```
static {
            registry = new HashMap<>();
            registry.put("cat", Cat.class);
        }
```

Then, for `AnimalWrangler.addAnimal("cat");` add to `addAnimal` method:

```
animals.add(registry.get("cat").newInstance());
```

Ought to solve it, so long as each class has a default constructor.

Comment: So when I save the animals I build the registry and save it to disc as well?

Comment: to save it to disc you would use serialization. Make the top parent class implement `Serializable` then write each instance to a separate file. To read back: `registry.get("cat").cast(objectReadFromDeserialization); See how to ser/deser here http://www.javatpoint.com/serialization-in-java

Comment: This is a much less verbose solution, however there is some performance loss using reflection to generate a new Instance

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're looking for a switch statement that does this for you, something like:

```
switch (type)
{
    type.equals("cat"): // Note hardcoding isn't the best idea and doesn't account for case sensitivity
        animals.add(new Cat());
        break;
    type.equals("horse"):
        animals.add(new Horse());
        break;
    // Add other animals in a similar fashion.
    default:
        throw new exception();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there an alternative to hardcoding?
If I was a lazy programmer, how could I avoid writing out a new switch every time I make a new class?

Comment: @jackoverflow The hardcoding you can solve with an enum, something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667243/using-enum-values-as-string-literals.
I wouldn't know how to avoid adding new animals to the switch.