# assign enum value to a string based on scanner input in java

Tags: java, string, enums, int

Ok, i'm very new to java and coding overall, and I have this assignment where I have to take user input , which will be a month, day and year, and multiply the month by the day and compare it to the last two digits of the year to check wether its a magic day or its not. While I accomplished this if the user only uses numbers as an input, I want to try and do another program where the users inputs the Month(Ex. April(not 4)) and I want to see if its possible for the program to check the enum, check for April and its value, and assign its value to the String month which then I will convert to a int. Sorry if my explanation is messy, But I explained to the best of my ability and feel free to ask if your confused about something.

Here's my code so far:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package magicadvanced;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author yfernandez
 */
public class MagicAdvanced {
    public enum Months{
        January(1),February(2),March(3),April(4),May(5),June(6),July(7),August(8),September(9),October(10),November(11),December(12);

        private int value;

        Months(int value){
            this.value = value;
        }


        public int valueInt(){
            return value;
        }
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner ls=new Scanner(System.in);
        String month,year,yrTwo;
        int day,yearInt;
        System.out.println("Please enter a month.");
        month = ls.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter a day.");
        day = ls.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the year.");
        year = ls.next();
        yrTwo = year.substring(2,4); //getting last two characters of the string year
        yearInt = Integer.valueOf(yrTwo);// converting last two character of the string year into an integer
        System.out.println(yearInt*2);//this is a just a test code to check if my conversion to integer works, will remove when program is done

    }
}
```

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667243/using-enum-values-as-string-literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to almost never try to create a custom enum for temporal units. The Java API already provides all the necessary tools to handle dates. Esp. Java 8, that brought significant improvements. You should take a look at resources like [this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) and [this](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/java-8-datetime-api-tutorial/) for insights on the main features of the Java datetime API.

The following code snippet gives you an idea how to process months.

```
Month month = Month.valueOf("FEBRUARY");

System.out.println(month.getValue());
// output: 2
System.out.println(month.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, Locale.UK));
// output: February
```

In case you want to parse a String representing a date, you should use should use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), as for e.g. shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22463063/2231685).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to parse the string input and convert that into an Enum value of the month constants

```
Months x = Months.valueOf("JAnuary")
```

will init x to january...

then getting the value is the same you did:

```
int val = x.getValue()
```

then after that you can do all you need  with the int.