# Return String from enum

Tags: java

I want to use this enum structure in order to return string.

```
public enum Exchanges {

    PROCESSING("processing");

    private final String type;

    Exchanges(final String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return type;
    }
}
```

When I use `Exchanges.PROCESSING` I get error:

```
Syntax error, insert "VariableDeclarators" to complete 
 LocalVariableDeclaration
```

How I can fix this issue?

Comment: `Exchanges e = Exchanges.PROCESSING` should work fine. Please show your code.

Comment: Yes, but I want to use the code in case like this: `channel.exchangeDeclare(Exchanges.PROCESSING, BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC);`

Comment: Please show [mcve]

Comment: Please show use the code relative to `channel.exchangeDeclare`

Comment: and what types does that method accept as parameters

Comment: channel.exchangeDeclare(String exchange , BuiltinExchangeType obj)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Enum values as String literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667243/using-enum-values-as-string-literals)

Comment: Tagged it as a duplicate because seemingly that is exactly what the OP wants to do and the dupe target shows several ways of achieving it.

Answer (score 3):

```
channel.exchangeDeclare(String exchange , BuiltinExchangeType obj)
```

should be

```
channel.exchangeDeclare(Exchanges exchange , BuiltinExchangeType obj)
```

or you should change the method call

```
channel.exchangeDeclare(Exchanges.PROCESSING, BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC);
```

to

```
channel.exchangeDeclare(Exchanges.PROCESSING.getType(), BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC);
```

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to call just `Exchanges.PROCESSING` without `getType()`

Comment: Well surely there is. And it returns you an object of type `Exchanges`. Which is not a `String`.

Comment: Then don't use an enum. Because that's not how an enum works.

Comment: Yes. As @Ben said, maybe you want to use constants, not enums.