# Thymeleaf does not recognize the span-tag

Tags: html-table, thymeleaf

I just wanted to have different colors for the different enum values in my DataTable. I also need `th:text` for my filter I created.

What can I do so that I can use `th:text` and keep my span formatting?

```html
<td class="incident" th:text="${ticket.getStatus().toString()}">
    <a th:if="${ticket.getStatus().toString()} == 'OPEN'">
        <span th:text="${ticket.getStatus().toString()}" class="badge text-white" style="background-color: #F93154"></span>
    </a>
    <a th:if="${ticket.getStatus().toString()} == 'IN_PROCESS'">
        <span th:text="${ticket.getStatus().toString()}" class="badge text-white" style="background-color: #FFEA00"></span>
    </a>
    <a th:if="${ticket.getStatus().toString()} == 'CLOSED'">
        <span th:text="${ticket.getStatus().toString()}" class="badge text-white" style="background-color: #00E676"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
<td class="incident" th:text="${ticket.getStatus().toString()}">
```

to this:

```
<td class="incident">
```

The reason is that the `th:text` expression in the `<td>` tag will cause all child content to be ignored.

---

You can also clean up the Thymeleaf a bit by changing `getStatus()` to just `status`, since Thymeleaf will automatically apply JavaBean naming rules to the field name `status` and acutally invoke `getStatus()` behind the scenes.

---

I would also recommend considering updating your enum, so that it can return string values directly - see [Using Enum values as String literals](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6667243/12567365). This will further allow you to simplify your Thymeleaf, and get rid of all those `.toString()` methods embedded in the template.

For example, assume you have the enum:

```java
public enum Status {
    OPEN, IN_PROCESS, CLOSED;
}
```

You can change that to the following:

```java
public enum Status {
    OPEN("Open"),
    IN_PROCESS("In Process"),
    CLOSED("Closed");

    private final String label;

    private Status(String s) {
        label = s;
    }
    
    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }
    
    // toString and comparison methods not shown
}
```

Now each enum has a related string value (the "label") which you can use as follows:

```html
<table>
    <td class="incident">
        <a th:if="${ticket.status.label} == 'Open'">
            <span th:text="${ticket.status.label}" 
                  class="badge text-white" 
                  style="background-color: #F93154"></span>
        </a>
        <a th:if="${ticket.status.label} == 'In Progress'">
            <span th:text="${ticket.status.label}" 
                  class="badge text-white" 
                  style="background-color: #FFEA00"></span>
        </a>
        <a th:if="${ticket.status.label} == 'Closed'">
            <span th:text="${ticket.status.label}" 
                  class="badge text-white" 
                  style="background-color: #00E676"></span>
        </a>
    </td>
</table>
```